# UISlider Available Value

Tags: iphone, uislider

I would like to know how to reproduce the UISlider appearance of streaming audio/video in the native iPhone player. I have it figured out except how to reproduce the available section and the empty part for the section not available.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1407026/Screen%20shot%202010-01-14%20at%2011.16.10%20PM.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1407026/Screen%20shot%202010-01-14%20at%2011.16.10%20PM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may end up discovering that that control isn't a UISlider as you know it. It could be a subclass or a completely different control that simply resembles a UISider.

I don't know this as a 100% true fact, but I say it because this control and the UISlider control both behave quite differently and have slightly different appearances.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating a UIProgressBar behind a UISlider(that had a hollowed out middle track). Looks pretty close, I'm happy with it. I'm still interested in seeing alternate solutions though.